# Dynamically shade datatable row based on MySQL Relation

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I am currently using jQuery Datatables to display relational data between multiple tables, jEditable to edit the table value, and UI Dropable for sorting. But for the life of me I cannot understand how to shade the rows based on relation. Example:

```
ID | Title | Parent

1 | Main Page     | 0
2 | Main Page 2   | 0
3 | Sub of Main   | 1
4 | Sub of Main 2 | 2
```

I would like to shade ID's 1 and 2 one color, and ID's 3, and 4 a different color. The table already works fine, but do I set a nested class something like "parent" and "child" to color in css?

**EDIT**

Tried using nested classes and then in css shading those TD's but it is still defaulting to the themeroller even after my css is placed after the themeroller theme.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the themeroller style has a more specific selector.
You might have to put the lame !important bit in your styles.

Answer (score 0):

When fetching your json from the server

```
{
  "sEcho": 1,
  "iTotalRecords": "57",
  "iTotalDisplayRecords": "57",
  "aaData": [
    [
      "Gecko",
      "Firefox 1.0",
      "Win 98+ / OSX.2+",
      "1.7",
      "A"
    ]
]
}
```

you need to fetch additional data,so your json looks like

```
{
      "sEcho": 1,
      "iTotalRecords": "57",
      "iTotalDisplayRecords": "57",
      "aaData": [
        [
          "Gecko",
          "Firefox 1.0",
          "Win 98+ / OSX.2+",
          "1.7",
          "<section data-hues='blue'>A</section>"
        ]
    ]
    }
```

The above displays `A` plus you have access to all information in the `data-*`For instance

`php`

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM City limit 10 ";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

$output = array(
        "sEcho" => "300",
        "iTotalRecords" => "321",
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => "10",
        "aaData" => array()
    );

     while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {    
     $output['aaData'][] = array($row["ID"],$row["Name"],$row["CountryCode"],$row["District"],'<section class="red" data-sn="'.$row["ID"].'">'.$row["Population"].'</section>');
    }

    echo json_encode( $output );

    /* free result set */
    $result->free();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

on the client side,have the class `.red{background-color:red;}`

I even tried this and it works.Cheers.